# How to get selected text from DIV using javascript ( working on IE7-8 )?

Tags: javascript, select, html, highlight

How to get highlighted text from DIV using javascript ?

Comment: When you say "selected text", do you mean the text within the `<div>` or that which is highlighted (selected) within the `<div>`?

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
 if (window.getSelection)
 {
     txt = window.getSelection();
 }
 else if (document.getSelection)
 {
     txt = document.getSelection();
 }
 else if (document.selection)
 {
     txt = document.selection.createRange().text;
 }
 else return;
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's try.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<title>Highlighted text</title>

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
if(!window.Kolich){
                Kolich = {};
            }

            Kolich.Selector = {};
            // getSelected() was borrowed from CodeToad at
            // http://www.codetoad.com/javascript_get_selected_text.asp
            Kolich.Selector.getSelected = function(){
                var t = '';
                if(window.getSelection){
                    t = window.getSelection();
                }else if(document.getSelection){
                    t = document.getSelection();
                }else if(document.selection){
                    t = document.selection.createRange().text;
                }
                return t;
            }

            Kolich.Selector.mouseup = function(){
                var st = Kolich.Selector.getSelected();
                if(st!=''){
                    alert("You selected:\n"+st);
                }
            }

            $(document).ready(function(){
                $(document).bind("mouseup", Kolich.Selector.mouseup);
            });
</script>
</head>
<body>
Select some text on the page ...
</body>
</html>
```

**You can customize the data of highlighted text on this function. The highlighted text is `st`**

```
Kolich.Selector.mouseup = function () {
    var st = Kolich.Selector.getSelected();
    if (st != '') {
        alert("You selected:\n" + st);
    }
}
```